# Rancher: rancher app requires username and password

Tags: docker, rancher

i installed rancher v0.4.2 container using Docker application, every thing is fine, but when im triyin to get access to rancher UI, i got popup that requires username and password, is there any default username/password to get access ?

Docker run command :

```
sudo docker run -d --restart=always -e CATTLE_DB_CATTLE_MYSQL_HOST=****.*****.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com -e CATTLE_DB_CATTLE_MYSQL_PORT=3306 -e CATTLE_DB_CATTLE_MYSQL_NAME=cattle -e CATTLE_DB_CATTLE_USERNAME=**** -e CATTLE_DB_CATTLE_PASSWORD=**** -p 8080:8080 rancher/server:0.4.2
```

Answer (score 3):

Run the below command,
docker exec -ti [CONTAINER ID / CONTAINER NAME] reset-password

You will get a new password for the "admin" user.

Answer (score 2):

v0.4.2 is not the version you want.  It's ridiculously old (Jan 12, 2015) and possibly before we had even announced the company and project exist.

Comment: i tried the stable and lastest version but i got the same issue :/

Comment: There is no access control enabled by default, are you staying with an empty database or over that was  previously used for rancher?  Are you sure you're going to the right url?  The only time http basic auth is used and presented to a browser is for accessing the API directly, access control is on, and you're not already logged in through the regular UI.